# mean of items in a list corresponding to same date in another list python

Tags: python, list

I am small problem with calculating the mean of items in a list. I hope somebody can save me from my turmoil.
I have two lists A and B such as

```
A = [3,2,1,9,4]
B = [1980,1980,1988,1988,2000]
```

Now I want to calculate the mean of the items in A which have the same dates in B.
So that eventually I will have

```
1980: 2.5
1988: 5
2000: 4
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you use external libraries. If so I would suggest looking at pandas. You can create a dataframe with two columns ["year","value"]. And then do a groupby on field 'year' and take a mean() of the aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to group the values per year together, then perform calculations on that, eg:

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = [3,2,1,9,4]
B = [1980,1980,1988,1988,2000]

yearvals = defaultdict(list)
for year, val in zip(B, A):
    yearvals[year].append(val)

for year, vals in yearvals.iteritems():
    print year, sum(vals, 0.0) / len(vals)
```

Output:

```
2000 4.0
1988 5.0
1980 2.5
```

Comment: thanks. i don't want to be annoying or ungrateful but there is a minor typo in your code. yearval should be yearvals!

Comment: `sum(vals, 0.0)` looks so better than the ugly `sum(vals) / float(len(vals))` that I use in my answers. +1 for that.

Comment: @user2215228 so it should - and it's now corrected - thank you. I originally had different names, but realised I wasn't being consistent, so I changed them in the post and not my editor :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary note though, that it means all the summing is done as floats which can be occasionally be quicker, but on the other hand, sometimes slower, so sometimes it's better to let them sum as ints

Answer (score 0):

A numpy solution would be

```
import numpy as np

A = [3,2,1,9,4]
B = [1980,1980,1988,1988,2000]

a = np.array(A)
b = np.array(B)

for year in set(b):
    print year, a[b == year].mean()
```

Prints

```
2000 4.0
1988 5.0
1980 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a reference defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

reference_dict = defaultdict(list)

A = [3,2,1,9,4]
B = [1980,1980,1988,1988,2000]

for i, year in enumerate(B):
    reference_dict[year].append(A[i])

for year, values in reference_dict.iteritems():
    print(year, sum(values, 0.0)/len(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> val_list = np.array([list(pair) for pair in zip(B,A)])
>>> val_list
array([[1980,    3],
       [1980,    2],
       [1988,    1],
       [1988,    9],
       [2000,    4]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(val_list,columns=['year','value'])
>>> df
   year  value
0  1980      3
1  1980      2
2  1988      1
3  1988      9
4  2000      4
>>> df.groupby(['year'],as_index=False).mean()
   year  value
0  1980    2.5
1  1988    5.0
2  2000    4.0
```

Comment: `DataFrame.from_records(zip(A, B)).groupby(1).mean()` is fine :) (eg: no need for the explicit `np.array` creation here)

Comment: Very True! I like to be explicit when answering problems, so the reader has a better understanding.